# django dynamic FilePathField

Tags: django, dynamic, models

```
class Project(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)
    main_file = models.FilePathField(path="/home/mn/myfiles/%s" % slug)
```

This code doesn't work, just illustrating what I'd like to do. 
I want to fill in `FilePathField` when object is accessed (ie. when it is updated in django admin, not when it's created).

Is there a hook where you can set fields just before they are filled? Something like `object.on_get(instance):` ... perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what your intentions here are.

Since Model instances are just Python classes, you can do this by a method on the Project class:

```
class Project(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def main_file(self):
         return "/home/mn/myfiles/%s" % self.slug
```

If you want to manually specify a location outside of `MEDIA_ROOT` to upload files to, you will need to subclass `django.db.models.fields.files.FileField` and overwrite [the `__init__` method](http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/fields/files.py#L222).